# Problem with restoring a Blackberry configuration database on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database, restore

I am attempting to restore a Blackberry configuration database on Microsoft SQL Server 2005. The command goes like this:

restore database besmgmt-test from disk = "C:\besmgmt-test.bak"; with move "besmgmt-test" to "E:\Data\besmgmt-test.mdf", move "besmgmt-test_log" to E:\Logs\besmgmt-test.ldf"

When I try to execute it, I receive the error "Incorrect syntax near '-'."

I've figured out that it doesn't like the dashes in the database's name, because I tested it out on another database without dashes. Even tried putting quotes around the database name in the command, but still received an error.

Is there any way around this besides changing the database's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Square-Brackets] around the name